# What does Lulu say?

Tags: league-of-legends

What are the quotes that Lulu can say while casting? Almost all of them are amusing but some seem to be more nonsensical than others, like 'Frog Ovulating!'. It would be nice to have a list to compare against.

Comment: Its' "Transmogulate!". [Full list of quotes here](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Lulu_the_Fae_Sorceress/Background#Quotes).

Comment: [Here](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Lulu_the_Fae_Sorceress/Background) are Lulu's quotes. What you are looking for is "Transmogulate!"

Comment: @RavenDreamer How is a question regarding the dialog of a game not constructive?

Comment: @GWLlosa Let me ask in this way: How is a question regarding the dialog of a game construtive?

Comment: @Michel As a hearing-impaired gamer I personally find questions like these to be very helpful and constructive as I often have a great deal of difficulty hearing and/or discerning game dialog. Additionally, I find their arbitrary dismissal to be particularly insulting.

Comment: This isn't a question about the game, though. It's "Identify this sound effect".

Comment: @RavenDreamer how is this significantly different from a plot or story question?

Comment: @NickT You mean other than the fact that this does not involve plot or story?

Comment: @RavenDreamer I was wondering why they would be constructive while this isn't.  Magnitude-wise, this may not rank as high, but it's still positive.  Please don't be so dismissive.

Comment: @RavenDreamer I think there are ~125 questions about Easter Eggs, which aren't usually plot or story relevant.  They're just facets of the game that are there as subtle homages/amusements.  One of the LoL champion's remarks may itself be such a subtlety, and a question requesting clarification thereof seems at least as relevant as the other 125?

Comment: @NickT Because it's not a question about the game. It's a question related to your hearing (or inability thereof). If the question was, "Why does Lulu say, 'Transmogulate'?", it would still be a crappy question, but it would at least be about a problem in the game.

Comment: I believe that his debate could bring good results, why we don't keep it on the [Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35/the-bridge)?

Comment: @NickT It seems this question has been answered. Could you mark it to remove it from unanswered list please? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Here](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Lulu_the_Fae_Sorceress/Background) a list with all Lulu's quotes.

The one mentioned was "Transmogulate!" that occurs when Whimsy is cast on an enemy.

A little [trivia](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Lulu_the_Fae_Sorceress/SkinsTrivia) about Lulu's quote:

> - Casting  Help, Pix! on an enemy will place a debuff on the target and    the tooltip reads "Hey! Listen!" at the end of it. This is a
>     reference to Navi from The Legend of Zelda: Ocarina of Time.
> - Her movement quote "Yup, that tasted purple." is likely a reference    to Philip Fry's similar quote from the Futurama episode "The Why of Fry" ("Did 
>     everything just taste purple for a second?")

Comment: I always wondered where that "that tasted purple" originated from. Thanks.

Comment: @nimcap No problem, thanks to +DaveMcClelland too to make the reference to Futurama, I was not sure about it so I skip adding that info, and it doesn't show in the wiki.